# Not enter in a switch case in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, switch-statement

I can't enter in the case 2 of the switch statement and I don't know why. If I remove the do while loop the code runs perfectly. It's about something with the memory of the structure array? Here is the code:

```
class Notebook {

        struct Student
        {
            public String id;
            public String name;
            public void showInfo(Student x) {
                Console.WriteLine("\t ID: " + x.id);
                Console.WriteLine("\t Name: " + x.name);
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args){

            bool display = true;

            int studentNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Student[] students = new Student[studentNum];

            do {

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("1.- Insert register");
                Console.WriteLine("2.- Show register");
                Console.WriteLine("3.- Exit");


                String opc = Console.ReadLine();


                switch (opc) {

                    case "1":
                        Console.Clear();
                        for(int i = 0; i < students.Length; ++i){
                            Console.WriteLine("Name of the student " + (i+1));
                            students[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("ID of the student " + (i+1));
                            students[i].id = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        Console.Clear();
                        for(int i = 0; i < students.Length; ++i){
                            students[i].showInfo(students[i]);
                        }
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("bye");
                        display = false;
                        break;

                }

            }while(display);

        }
    }
```

I think that is "something" in the memory of opc string that avoids the case 2.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Your code looks fine at a first glance, but a debugger will allow you to see program flow and the detailed contaents of the objects that variables represent.

Comment: just do debug. Can you verify, that `opc == "2"`?

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, I write one Console.WriteLine(opc) after setting the value and shows me  "2" and nothing more. If I wrote "3", the program finish perfectly.

Comment: no, do not `Console.WriteLine(opc)`. Debug and check if `opc == "2"` in immediate window.

Comment: @vasily.sib I wrote the if statement and the program jumps over it. As if it were not written.

Comment: you don't need to write anything. Debug and check if opc == "2" in **immediate window**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `Console.Clear` statement that you run at start of do while loop. Comment that line and you will see that your code is going to `case "2"`.

Its going to case "2" even in your original code, but console is every time being cleared at start of do while loop and so you don't see the statements written by case "2" logic.

There is no memory problem as you suspected.

The do while loop should have  Console.Clear commented as in code below.

```
 do {

            //Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("1.- Insert register");
            Console.WriteLine("2.- Show register");
            Console.WriteLine("3.- Exit");
```

Comment: That's works perfectly! I need to have more careful about my code.

Comment: Yes, this type of problem is very subtle and can easily come up while writing code.

Answer (score 0):

add a Console.ReadLine();  before break case "2".

```
case "2":
                    Console.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        students[i].showInfo(students[i]);
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
```

You write students informations and Call Console.Clear() after that